# show a fixed bottom footer on scroll up

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onscroll

I want to show a footer fixed to the bottom of the screen only when the user scrolls up. Similar to [Medium Posts](https://medium.com/@chazhutton/a-series-of-observations-explained-via-port-it-notes-976067e52f2)

I have the effect working on my header but I can't get it to work for my footer

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ymusmky4/)

```js
var didScroll;
var lastScrollTop = 0;
var delta = 5;
var footerHeight = $('blog-footer').outerHeight();

$(window).scroll(function(event) {
  didScroll = true;
});

setInterval(function() {
  if (didScroll) {
    hasScrolled();
    didScroll = false;
  }
}, 250);

function hasScrolled() {
  var st = $(this).scrollTop();

  if (Math.abs(lastScrollTop - st) <= delta) {
    return;
  }

  if (st > lastScrollTop && st > footerHeight) {

    $('blog-footer').removeClass('footer-down').addClass('footer-up');
  } else {

    if (st + $(window).height() < $(document).height()) {
      $('blog-footer').removeClass('footer-up').addClass('footer-down');
    }
  }

  lastScrollTop = st;
}
```

```css
.blog-footer {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  background: red;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="blog-footer footer-down">
  <p>Content</p>
</div>
```

Can anyone see what I'm missing to get this to work?

Comment: This could just be a typo but the selector `$("blog-footer")` is missing a dot. It's not matching anything the way it is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a small (read *serious*) error. May be a typo! That's `$(".blog-footer")` with a `.`.

Added a snippet for the same, in a simpler way. See the JavaScript and CSS part please.

```js
$(function () {
  last_scroll_position = $(window).scrollTop();
  $(window).scroll(function () {
    if (last_scroll_position > $(window).scrollTop())
      $("footer").addClass("show");
    else
      $("footer").removeClass("show");
    last_scroll_position = $(window).scrollTop();
  });
});
```

```css
* {font-family: 'Segoe UI'; margin: 0; padding: 0; list-style: none;}
p {margin: 0 0 5px; text-align: justify;}

footer {height: 50px; line-height: 50px; width: 100%; text-align: center; background-color: #f99; position: fixed; bottom: -50px; -webkit-transition: all 0.5s linear; -o-transition: all 0.5s linear; transition: all 0.5s linear;}
footer.show {bottom: 0;}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<p>Can we do something easier and similar instead of all those math?</p>
<p>Some long content now.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Architecto distinctio, itaque dolores sunt quo facilis doloremque quidem minima. Nesciunt adipisci ex consectetur! Magnam, illo qui voluptas placeat quos expedita nulla!</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Doloribus in illo corrupti quos hic ipsam eaque eligendi assumenda itaque numquam ullam, praesentium cumque perferendis officia, veniam totam! Quasi ab, necessitatibus.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Architecto distinctio, itaque dolores sunt quo facilis doloremque quidem minima. Nesciunt adipisci ex consectetur! Magnam, illo qui voluptas placeat quos expedita nulla!</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Doloribus in illo corrupti quos hic ipsam eaque eligendi assumenda itaque numquam ullam, praesentium cumque perferendis officia, veniam totam! Quasi ab, necessitatibus.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Architecto distinctio, itaque dolores sunt quo facilis doloremque quidem minima. Nesciunt adipisci ex consectetur! Magnam, illo qui voluptas placeat quos expedita nulla!</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Doloribus in illo corrupti quos hic ipsam eaque eligendi assumenda itaque numquam ullam, praesentium cumque perferendis officia, veniam totam! Quasi ab, necessitatibus.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Architecto distinctio, itaque dolores sunt quo facilis doloremque quidem minima. Nesciunt adipisci ex consectetur! Magnam, illo qui voluptas placeat quos expedita nulla!</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Doloribus in illo corrupti quos hic ipsam eaque eligendi assumenda itaque numquam ullam, praesentium cumque perferendis officia, veniam totam! Quasi ab, necessitatibus.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Architecto distinctio, itaque dolores sunt quo facilis doloremque quidem minima. Nesciunt adipisci ex consectetur! Magnam, illo qui voluptas placeat quos expedita nulla!</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Doloribus in illo corrupti quos hic ipsam eaque eligendi assumenda itaque numquam ullam, praesentium cumque perferendis officia, veniam totam! Quasi ab, necessitatibus.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Architecto distinctio, itaque dolores sunt quo facilis doloremque quidem minima. Nesciunt adipisci ex consectetur! Magnam, illo qui voluptas placeat quos expedita nulla!</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Doloribus in illo corrupti quos hic ipsam eaque eligendi assumenda itaque numquam ullam, praesentium cumque perferendis officia, veniam totam! Quasi ab, necessitatibus.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Architecto distinctio, itaque dolores sunt quo facilis doloremque quidem minima. Nesciunt adipisci ex consectetur! Magnam, illo qui voluptas placeat quos expedita nulla!</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Doloribus in illo corrupti quos hic ipsam eaque eligendi assumenda itaque numquam ullam, praesentium cumque perferendis officia, veniam totam! Quasi ab, necessitatibus.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Architecto distinctio, itaque dolores sunt quo facilis doloremque quidem minima. Nesciunt adipisci ex consectetur! Magnam, illo qui voluptas placeat quos expedita nulla!</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Doloribus in illo corrupti quos hic ipsam eaque eligendi assumenda itaque numquam ullam, praesentium cumque perferendis officia, veniam totam! Quasi ab, necessitatibus.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Architecto distinctio, itaque dolores sunt quo facilis doloremque quidem minima. Nesciunt adipisci ex consectetur! Magnam, illo qui voluptas placeat quos expedita nulla!</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Doloribus in illo corrupti quos hic ipsam eaque eligendi assumenda itaque numquam ullam, praesentium cumque perferendis officia, veniam totam! Quasi ab, necessitatibus.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Architecto distinctio, itaque dolores sunt quo facilis doloremque quidem minima. Nesciunt adipisci ex consectetur! Magnam, illo qui voluptas placeat quos expedita nulla!</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Doloribus in illo corrupti quos hic ipsam eaque eligendi assumenda itaque numquam ullam, praesentium cumque perferendis officia, veniam totam! Quasi ab, necessitatibus.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Architecto distinctio, itaque dolores sunt quo facilis doloremque quidem minima. Nesciunt adipisci ex consectetur! Magnam, illo qui voluptas placeat quos expedita nulla!</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Doloribus in illo corrupti quos hic ipsam eaque eligendi assumenda itaque numquam ullam, praesentium cumque perferendis officia, veniam totam! Quasi ab, necessitatibus.</p>
<footer>Footer Here</footer>
```

Comment: ek! I've edited that now so it is adding and removing the footer class! I'm not getting it to calculate the height and to change the position however. I know I could do this with css based on the class - but with the header I have it working with just this js - is there something else I have wrong?

Comment: @Ciaran Did you just see my updated answer with a snippet to play around?

Comment: What do you think about it @Ciaran?

Comment: is there a way to have this start of shown? This effect with the header for example which uses very similar code to that I initially posted
https://visible.vc/blog/

Comment: Ha ha... Copy the same code to the `header` just swap the `-` and `0` in the CSS.

Comment: no I mean so that when you first start off on the page - the footer is shown. for now when you first arrive on page it is not shown. you have to scroll down then scroll up to get it to show. that make sense?

Comment: Okay, that's easy. Start with footer having the `show` class on by default.

Comment: @Ciaran Instead of `<footer>Footer Here</footer>` give as `<footer class="show">Footer Here</footer>`

Answer (score 0):

Made another version of this: https://jsfiddle.net/h23oe67L/1/

Not that much jQuery (I think we could actually remove it all together):

```
var distanceToTop = 0;

var $window = $(window);
var header = $('.header');
var footer = $('.footer');

$window.scroll(function () {
    if ($window.scrollTop() < distanceToTop) {
        // we have scrolled up
        header.removeClass('header-up');
        header.addClass('header-down');
        footer.removeClass('footer-down');
        footer.addClass('footer-up');
    } else {
        // we scrolled down (or to the sides, make a separate case for this)
        header.removeClass('header-down');
        header.addClass('header-up');
        footer.removeClass('footer-up');
        footer.addClass('footer-down');
    }

    distanceToTop = $window.scrollTop();
});
```